# Why is Scout trying to alter files in non-specified directory?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, scout-sass

I've used Scout before but haven't run into this problem... when I save a change to an scss file (the scss directory is specified as the "input" folder) which should then rewrite my styles.css file (in the specified "output" folder), I am given an error from scout stating "Error on line 61 of c: File not found or cannot be read:", and it then point to an image file in a separate folder within the site I'm working on.

Why could this be happening? I tried create two Scout projects for the same site: One where the root folder of the site is selected as the main directory and one where the folder a few levels into the site containing the scss and css files are held, but got the same results from both. I don't know why scout would be going into an image folder when the input/output folder are explicitly selected.

How can I make it so Scout just detects changes to my scss files and rewrites the css file without any nonsense about image files? Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:** I hope this can give some insight, but the file that seems to be causing the error is being described in a location it is not in: C:\Users\me\Desktop\project/logo.png

There *is* a logo.png file in another location (C:\Users\me\Desktop\project\apply\assets\img\logo.png) but that doesn't seem to account for the error message. Very puzzled.

**Second Edit:** I'll try to give this one last bump with a little more info. At this point when I save a scss file I am still getting the same long error message in the scout app about an error, but my style.css file has stopped being affected at all since yesterday. The last message I got was a syntax error and then a very long backtrace message that looks something like this...

```
Backtrace:
C:/Users/me/Desktop/project/apply/assets/scss/_base.scss:6
C:/Users/me/Desktop/project/apply/assets/scss/style.scss:12
c:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-    3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/script/variable.rb:49:in `_perform'
c:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/script/node.rb:40:in `perform'
c:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:294:in `visit_prop'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2096:in `send'
```

Comment: Is Scout still supported...I thought it had been abandoned ages ago?

Comment: Eh- as far as I know it is? Like I said, I've been using it for some other projects with success.

Comment: Last commit was 2012...just saying.https://github.com/mhs/scout-app

Comment: Can you recommend an alternative?

Comment: Scout-App is still being maintained, it's had 4 major releases in the past year. It no longer relies on Java/Air/Ruby, it now uses Node-Sass, so it only supports Compass mixins, not gems, but is considerably faster now. http://Scout-App.io